# How to hide a preloader after a fully loaded document

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have to column layout on bootstrap modal, in the left column, display the list of uploaded filenames while in the right column display the preview of uploaded document if has a click event on one of the filename on the left column.

This is the div I used to display the document preview.

```
<div id="img-container">
  <div id="docs" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

and this was the ajax code I used to display the document.

```
  $('.pdf-docs').click( function () {
      var file = $(this).attr('data-file'); // filename display on the left
      var url  = $(this).attr('data-file-url')+'/'+file; // url where to get the file
      $.ajax({
        url:url,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        success:function(data) {
          $('#img-container #docs').html('<embed src="' + data.file_uploaded + '" width="100%" height="100%">');
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('div#waitme').waitMe({
                effect:  'stretch',
                bg:      'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',
                color:   '#000',
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
          $('#waitme').waitMe('hide');
        }
      });
  });
```

This ajax code, make a request on codeigniter controller which will return the path where the file located.

`div#waitme` is the parent of two column div where I implement the preloader.

The preloader on `beforesend:` render successfully but it will not stop or hide even the document is fully loaded.

Is there any best solution for this?

waitme source: https://github.com/vadimsva/waitMe

Comment: remove it from the dom?

Comment: no i can't do that, I need it to be there.